# Why has my garage door opener (139.53975SRT1) stopped working?

Tags: garage-door-opener

My garage door opener stopped working. I checked the power outlet it's plugged into and it's working. I checked other things (locks and springs) recommended by the manual and they seem ok to me. However when I try to turn on the lights inside the unit from the control panel it makes a clicking sound but the lamps don't light up. I'm comfortable with going inside the unit and do further testing but I need to know if it's worth it or should I ask for help from the pros.

Comment: If you are comfortable going in there- Trace where the Live goes in.Make sure somebody is with you for safety! Test if power is going at your local rated voltage. If its ok- look at the PCB's and check if any caps are bulging, discoloured,leaking.

Comment: Is it just the light that's not working, or is it the whole unit not working?

Comment: Link to [the manual](http://homeappliance.manualsonline.com/manuals/mfg/sears/13953975srt1_13953962srt1.html?idRes=4067067) for reference.

Comment: Bulbs dead?
By control panel, do you mean the remote control wall unit? Is it battery operated like mine, and the batteries are dead?
Did you accidentally reset the base unit and the remote control must be paired again with the unit?

Comment: I replaced the circuit board and now the lights come on and the board reacts to the remote (blinking) but the motor doesn't start (doesn't even make a noise). There is a large capacitor between the CB and the motor. When I press the remote there is no voltage on that capacitor legs.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to consult the manuals troubleshooting section - usually the number of flashes/clicks indicates what the problem might be.

The most common issues I've seen are related to the safety sensors mounted near the door.  Sometimes they get knocked out of alignment, or there could be a short in the wire due to a staple.  The manual will likely provide instructions for temporarily shorting out this connection to bypass it.

It might also have overheated if you were operating it a lot - assuming you didn't burn out the motor, usually in this scenario you just need to wait for the unit to cool down.

The worst case scenario is that either the motor or logic board are dead.  You might be able to repair it, but the vendor will likely advice just replacing the parts.